# Grouping and getting unique values from one day(until it changes) in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table where I record events from one day. The day starts with event 'A' it continues with event 'B' and so on. Sometimes, at the end of the day it generates a new 'A' event. This new event I want to ignore. If I select all 'A's from that day, the second ones also gets included.

So, this is how it looks:

I have entries in a database like:
Date         Event
12:56:18 PM  A
12:56:19 PM  A
12:56:20 PM  B
12:56:21 PM  B
12:56:22 PM  B
12:56:23 PM  C
12:56:24 PM  C
12:56:25 PM  A
12:56:26 PM  A
12:56:27 PM  A

The table records one event once every 10 secs or so.
I want to select intervals per day until values repeats, I need to get:

1. 
12:56:18 PM  A
12:56:19 PM  A

2. 
12:56:20 PM  B
12:56:21 PM  B
12:56:22 PM  B

3.
12:56:23 PM  C
12:56:24 PM  C

So I don't need the second 'A's 
I tried to select all 'A's from one day I get first one and last one
I tried with partition but I cannot understand how to get the first interval.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when event <> 'A' then date end) over (partition by cast(date as date)) as min_not_a
      from t
     ) t
where event <> 'A' or
      min_not_a is null or
      date < min_not_a;
```

This uses `cast(date as date)` to represent extracting the date from the column you call `date`.  The exact syntax may vary depending on your database.

Comment: Mainly this returns the tabel selection until the repeating 'A's?

Comment: @Lucian . . . This returns all rows except for the repeating `'A'`, which is how I interpret the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is variation of islands problem. As you've mentioned partitions I assume the dbms in question supports `row_number() over()` I use `sqlserver` syntax to populate sample table, you may need to change it.

```
create table dlog (
  dt date,
  tm time,
  evt varchar(10));

insert dlog(dt,tm,evt)
values
('20190101','12:56:18 PM','A'),
('20190101','12:56:19 PM','A'),
('20190101','12:56:20 PM','B'),
('20190101','12:56:21 PM','B'),
('20190101','12:56:22 PM','B'),
('20190101','12:56:23 PM','C'),
('20190101','12:56:24 PM','C'),
('20190101','12:56:25 PM','A'),
('20190101','12:56:26 PM','A'),
('20190101','12:56:27 PM','A'),
('20190102','12:56:18 PM','A'),
('20190102','12:56:19 PM','A'),
('20190102','12:56:20 PM','B'),
('20190102','12:56:21 PM','B'),
('20190102','12:56:22 PM','B'),
('20190102','12:56:23 PM','C'),
('20190102','12:56:24 PM','C'),
('20190102','12:56:25 PM','A'),
('20190102','12:56:26 PM','A'),
('20190102','12:56:27 PM','A')
;

select dt, tm, evt 
from (
    select dt, tm, evt
     , row_number() over(partition by dt order by tm) - row_number() over(partition by dt, evt  order by tm) grp
    from dlog
) t
where evt <> 'A' OR grp = 0
order by dt, tm;
```